# Add a jar file in android studio 0.3.2 version

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ksoap2

I am new to android studio and know nothing about it, i want to add the kSoap Jar file into my project, so i read many article on this but could not point my finger to it.

Articles read are :

http://articlesforprogramming.blogspot.in/2013/06/how-to-do-add-external-library-file-in.html

Also i read that there is an issue for [adding module in the studio](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62122), I have updated my build.gradle file with the following line

```
dependencies {
compile files('Libraries/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.1.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
```

}

and rebuild my project, but when i try to import the ksoap it gets imported but i cannot make use of the classes present in ksoap like soapobject etc.

One thing i learned is that you need to place your JAR files in a libs folder but when i created a test project i was not able to see the libs folder so i created a new directory and named it libs so am i doing this right?

[image]

Could you please guide me out on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always good to keep your jar libraries in **libs** directory. Then you can try this method:

```
dependencies {
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
 compile project('...')
```

}

Think also about switching to Android Studio 0.4.0 (which is available right now). More stable and many fixes since 0.3.2 version.

Comment: Thanks for the help i guess updating my project was the solution thanks a lot @adek

Answer (score 0):

use only one

```
dependencies {

compile '....'

compile '....'

compile '....'

}
```

and remove file('.....')

instead write like above..

Comment: I did as you suggested now its giving me an error like this Failed to refresh Gradle project 'HelloWorldAndroid':
           The description Libraries/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.1.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar is invalid
           Build file '/Users/Somename/Desktop/HelloWorldAndroidProject/HelloWorldAndroid/build.gradle' line: 28